# Django URL - Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: django, django-templates

I've encountered this error while trying to use the url tag to link to a view.  The error occurs on this line:

```
{% for algorithim in algorithims %}
```

in the template.

Not really sure where I'm going wrong here.. I think I've attached all the necessary info but let me know if you need to see anything else.

**Error :**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /wiki/algorithims/
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'wiki.views.algorithim.view' with arguments '(0,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**url.conf (wiki) :**

```
   from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

   urlpatterns = patterns('wiki.views',
       url(r'^$', 'index'),
       url(r'^algorithims/$', 'algorithims.index'),
       url(r'^algorithims/(?P<alg_id>\d+)/$', 'algorithims.view')
    )
```

**wiki.views.algorithim :**

```
@login_required
def index(request): 
    algorithims = Algorithms.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('wiki/algorithims/index.html', 
                          {'algorithims': algorithims 
                           },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**templates/wiki/algorithims/index.html :**

```
{% extends "wiki/base.html" %} 

{% block content %}
<div>
    {% if algorithims %}    
        {% for algorithim in algorithims %}
            <a href="{% url wiki.views.algorithim.view algorithim.alg_id %}">{{ algorithim.alg_name }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        No algorithims found!
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: fyp, it's "algorithm", not "algorithim"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is called `algorithms.view` in the urlconf but you've referred to it in the URL tag as `algorithm.view`, ie without the `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this post which asked a very similar question.

[Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643697/caught-noreversematch-while-rendering-reverse-for-with-arguments-1-and-k)